# Adding border to ListViewItem hides content

Tags: c#, xaml, listview

So I have a `ListView` with a `ListViewItem` which has a border to round the corners:

```
<ListView>
 <ListViewItem x:Name="easy_listViewItem" Height="35" Tag="easy" Margin="0,0,15,0" BorderBrush="White" FontSize="15.333" Content="Easy" Foreground="Black" Background="#FF27AE60" FontWeight="Bold">
   <ListViewItem.Template>
      <ControlTemplate>
           <Border CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF27AE60">
               <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
           </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </ListViewItem.Template>
</ListViewItem>
```

However, it seems because of the `Border` I can no longer see the `Content` of the `ListViewItem` does anyone know why?